# What is the correct way to define the argument of the logarithm on a region $G$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I know that the principle branch of the logarithm defined on the region $\mathbb{C}-\{z\leq 0\}$ is given as $\log(z) = \log(|z|) + i\theta$ where $-\pi<\theta<\pi$.

Suppose we have the region $G = \mathbb{C} - \{z: \Re(z) \geq 0 \text{ and } \Im(z) = \Re(z)\}$, that is the complex plane with a slit along the line $y=x$ in the first quadrant of the plane. I would like to construct the analogue of the principle branch of the logarithm on $G$. However I am not sure how to define the argument of $z$ on $G$.

Would I start on the positive real axis and travel anti-clockwise until I hit the excluded 'slit' and then for all the $z\in G$ that I cannot reach by going past this slit, I instead travel clockwise from the positive real axis to reach $z$, i.e. $$-\frac{7\pi}{4}<\theta< \frac{\pi}{4}?$$

So then the "principle branch" on $G$ would be $\log(z) = \log(|z|) + i\theta$, $-\frac{7\pi}{4}<\theta< \frac{\pi}{4}$ for any $z\in G$?

Comment: Any logarithmic function is defined up to an additive constant.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to define the principle branch on a different region, I know that all branches of the logarithm differ by $2\pi k i$

Comment: It is certainly a branch of the logarithm. However, I would not use the term "principal branch". In my opinion "principal branch" includes both the dominion and the choice of argument.